# Getting SharePoint news using rest API in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is there any rest API available to get the recent updates or news related to a site in SharePoint Online?

[How To Read The SharePoint News Using Rest API In SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-the-sharepoint-news-using-rest-api-in-spfx/)

I have found above post but it does not work for me as hitting the API's only gives error or irrelevant XML data.

So, I wanted to know if there is any way to get the news of SharePoint site using rest API ?

**Updated**:

**API**

> _api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx
>   AND PromotedState:2

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the api url you are using and also please update post with the error you are seeing for better understanding.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are setting the header to use odata v3, more info here; https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-the-sharepoint-news-using-rest-api-in-spfx/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the ending single quote. Update the API call to:

> _api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx AND PromotedState:2'

Furthermore, you'll need to encode this to use it. Change your spaces to %20 and your single quotes to %27 like this:

> _api/search/query?querytext=%27IsDocument:True%20AND%20FileExtension:aspx%20AND%20PromotedState:2%27